# Remote JSON READ and Parse

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Can anyone please help me with this?

I would like to read and parse a remote json and print it in a list box in Windows 7 Phone.

I googled and couldnt able to find an apt answer which works for me.

It would be good to get some tutorials or some code samples.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) is a mature library for parsing JSON and has specific support for Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Thank you, Also Can you please give me an example of how to read the json through the remote URL using isolatedstorage and store it in a string variable os that i can use the library thay you have given in your link.

Answer (score 0):

If you look on the json website (http://www.json.org/) you can find a list of libraries currently available for parsing JSON in C# and a link to how to create a parser yourself, if you would like to do that instead.